# How can I load file data in PHP using jQuery without error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in google chrome?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have following jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // notification list
    $.fn.listarNotificacoes = function() {
        return this.each(function() { 
            $.ajax({
                url : 'js/php-files/notificacao-listar.php',
                type : 'post',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#notification').html('<div align="center"><span class="aguarde-notification"></span></div>');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#notification').html(data);
                }
            });
        });  
    };

    $('#notification').listarNotificacoes();

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#notification').listarNotificacoes();
    },10000); //60000 = 1 min
});
```

In the PHP file (notificacao-listar.php), I have:

```
<?php
$notificacoes = $notificacaoBO->findByParam($notificacaoVO);
$count = count($notificacoes);
?>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="notification-load"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span><span class="badge"><?php echo $count ?></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $notificacaoVO = $notificacoes[$i];
    ?>
    <li class="notification-list">
        <strong><?php echo $notificacaoVO->getName(); ?></strong>
        <?php echo $notificacaoVO->getDescription(); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $notificacaoVO->getLink(); ?>"><?php echo '#'.$notificacaoVO->getId(); ?></a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

When I open in the chrome navigator, Ok. The problem is when open other navigator parallel on the same page.
I get the following error of chrome navigator:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
POST http://localhost/manager/js/php-files/notificacao-listar.php net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED jquery.min.js:4
send                                                                                         jquery.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax                                                                                jquery.min.js:4
listarNotificacoes                                                                           (index):39 
(anonymous function)                                                                         (index):57
```

How can I resolve this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: can you try changing the url to url : 'http://127.0.0.1/manager/js/php-files/notificacao-listar.php' to see if it's a host name related error?

Comment: Hi @satchcoder, thank you by help me. But, I tryed and get this error: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: Wow! Now I'm confused :D Can you open a tab on your browser and just put the http://localhost/manager/js/php-files/notificacao-listar.php ?

Comment: Yes @satchcoder. I can open the link http://localhost/manager/js/php-files/notificacao-listar.php in other tab in my browser and the notification are listed.

Comment: Do you have any Ad blocking extension in Chrome?

Comment: It's crazy! Because, I open the link localhost/manager in IE and after I open on chrome and the error happens. While I'm only using chrome the error not happen.

Comment: I not have extension about Ad blocking.

Comment: You can try the chrome extension postman that can help you debug the post request. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en